# automatic switch between the Wifi and ethernet in Linux using command line

Tags: wireless, networking

I want to switch between the Wifi and ethernet in Linux (Ubuntu 10.04) . I have searched many ways and I found it can be done using firestarter — autoswitch between wired and wireless networks .

For this I need to install the firestarter package in Ubuntu.

Is this the correct way for switching between eth0 and wifi ? I wanted to implement it using command line without installing any new packages.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`Connman(1)` can be used to prioritize your connections to prefer wired networks and auto-connect to wireles when the wired connection is unavailable.  It is supported by Intel, so it can be hostile to non-intel networking hardware: I can't use `Connman(1)` since my wifi driver won't set flags Intel expects to enable the adapter.  I get "no carrier" error and no wifi connection.  However, it seems to connect quickly when I plug in the wired connection.

You need to configure `/etc/connman/main.conf/main.conf`
with something like:

```
  BackgroundScanning = false
  DefaultAutoConnectTechnologies = ethernet,wifi 
  PreferredTechnologies = ethernet,wifi
  SingleConnectedTechnology = true
```

to ensure only wifi or ethernet is connected.  Then, use an interactive `connmanctl(1)` session as indicated by the man page  to connect to wifi the first time or edit the settings  file for your interface found in `/var/lib/connman` (this seems easier to me, but restart required.)  See `connman-service.config(5)`

If you have `ifupdown` or its variants installed, you might remove those to avoid collisions before installing `connman(1)`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)**  **Great first answer!**  Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

I created the script for connection and disconnection from wifi and ethernet

**Disconnect the wifi**

```
killall wpa_supplicant
wirelessname=`ls /sys/class/net | grep wlan* | head -1`
ifconfig $wirelessname down
```

**Connect the wifi**

```
wirelessname=`ls /sys/class/net | grep wlan* | head -1`
ifconfig $wirelessname up > /dev/null 2>&1 &
killall wpa_supplicant > /dev/null 2>&1 &
iwconfig $wirelessname power off > /dev/null 2>&1 &
wpa_passphrase $1 $2 > /root/wps.conf
wpa_supplicant -Dwext -i$wirelessname -c/root/wps.conf > /dev/null 2>&1 &
sleep 5
dhclient -r > /dev/null 2>&1 &
dhclient $wirelessname > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

**Connect Ethernet**

```
ifconfig $(ip link show | grep eth | grep state | awk '{printf $2}'| sed -e 's/:$//') up
ifconfig $(ifconfig | grep eth | awk '{print $1}'| head -1 ) $(ifconfig  | grep Bcast | awk '{printf $2}' | cut  -c6-) up
```

**Disconnect ethernet**

```
ifconfig $(ifconfig | grep eth | awk '{print $1}' | head -1 )  down
```